# Como criar uma variável inteira em hexadecimal?

Tags: c#, console, runtime

Estou tentando criar uma variável inteira em hexadecimal, mas ocorre um erro dizendo que não está no formato correto.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern short GetKeyState(int vKey);
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("config.txt");
    int TriggerButton = int.Parse(lines[0].Replace("Trigger Button: ", ""));
    int PanicButton  = int.Parse(lines[1].Replace("Panic Button: ", ""));
    Console.WriteLine(TriggerButton + "\n" + PanicButton);
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetKeyState(TriggerButton));
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

## Config.txt

```
Trigger Button: 0x12
Panic Button: 0x78
```

Tem alguma maneira de converter uma string para um inteiro hexadecimal sem perder o `0x`?

Comment: Pelo que entendi você quer pegar uma string no formato hexadecimal e transformar em inteiro. Segue [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eqepEg) com a resposta abaixo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem utilizar StringFormat, uma opção válida é utilizar

```
Convert.ToInt32 Method (String, Int32)
```

Int32 será a base, neste caso 16 Hexadecimal

```
int PanicButton = Convert.ToInt32(lines[1].Replace("Panic Button: ", ""), 16);

int TriggerButton = Convert.ToInt32(lines[0].Replace("Trigger Button: ", ""), 16);
```